# Laravel queue dispatch through error (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value) while dispatchNow does not

Tags: queue, laravel-7

Can any help me, I can not figure out.

```
UpdateVendorProdcutFromXml::dispatchNow($filePath, $class);
```

Works fine no error. But

```
UpdateVendorProdcutFromXml::dispatch($filePath, $class)
            ->onQueue('updating-products')
            ->delay(now()->addSeconds(5))
```

Through error in logs.

> (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value)

Comment: Probably you are using not using `unicode` as like `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` charset in your db. In your `database.php` change `'strict' => true` to `'strict' => false`, if above method not work. Then let me know

Comment: I have digged deaper and found promlem was with strtolower(). While running with dispatchNow there is no problem, but when running with dispatch() "General error: 1366" was throughn. @sta do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

add collation as utf8mb4_unicode_ci in phpmyadmin to thos table fields[image]